# Search company api linkedin

Tags: api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I want to search company by keyword.
[https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?keywords=is?oauth2_access_token={accesstoken}&format=json](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?keywords=is?oauth2_access_token=%7Baccesstoken%7D&format=json)

This url will lead to an error.
How could i modify it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be like

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(companies:(id,name,logo_url))?keywords=keyword?oauth2_access_token={accesstoken}&format=json
```

Comment: Is this outdated?

Comment: @EralpB Still works in 2017! Just replace the ```?``` after ```keyword``` with a ```&```.

Answer (score 5):

This link is not working. I think, it is outdated. I tried with to feed company name in url 
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(companies:(id,google,logo_url))?keywords=keyword?oauth2_access_token={accesstoken}&format=json. 
I am using https://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query=google&types=company,group,sitefeature.
just feed your company name instead of google.
It is working but you have install Cors everywhere plugin.